# Cron daemon not running in debian

Tags: linux, debian, scheduled-tasks, cron

I am using Jessie. Cron was working fine last week. But I just checked today and found out, it's not working anymore. When I restart upstart loads my custom tasks. But if I check

```
sudo service --status-all
```

Cron is shown marked as `[ - ]  cron`
When I execute `sudo service --status-all`, I get `[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!` in return. Manually starting cron service executes the tasks in crontab. But, the service is not starting on boot.

There is no problem with crontab task specification. They are working fine on my other machines running Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not run `crond` manually and see if it crashes? Read `/etc/init.d/crond` to see how it's started.

Comment: "... upstart loads my custom tasks" you might want to know that Debian does not use upstart, but rather, systemd. you can list all services via `sudo systemctl list-units -t service`. There you might find your failed cron service, and you can try restarting it by issuing something like `sudo systemctl restart cron.service` . If that fails, check `journalctl -xe` for errors. If the error logs don't make sense to you, post them here and we'll see what we can do =)